# Simple Form Error Notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, simple-form

I am trying to figure out how to use Simple Form with Rails, Devise, Omniauth and Bootstrap. I have several problems, but one of them is error notifications.

I have a devise sign in and sign up form inside Bootstrap modals.  The registration form is as follows. Note that I removed the `required: true` function from the form because I don't like the asterisk being appended to the label (but I did try putting it back to see if the error notifications would work).

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#myRModal", :method => 'get' %>
  </li>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myRModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myRModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color:black">Register</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
            <div class="facebookauth"> <%= link_to "Register with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %></div>
            <br />
          <% end -%>
          <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
            <div class="linkedinauth"> <%= link_to "Register with LinkedIn", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %></div>
            <br />
          <% end -%>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">



  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
     <%= f.error_notification %>

     <div class="form-inputs" style="padding-left:20%; text-align:left; color:black;">

       <%= f.input :first_name, placeholder: 'Enter your first name', autofocus: true, :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40} %>
       <%= f.input :last_name, placeholder: 'Enter your surname', autofocus: true, :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40} %>
       <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'Enter email',  autofocus: true, :input_html => {:maxlength => 25, :size => 40} %>
       <%= f.input :password, placeholder: 'At least 8 characters', :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40} %>
       <%= f.input :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Confirm your password',  :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40} %>
     </div>

     <div class="form-actions" style="padding-left:20%; padding-top:5%; text-align:left; color:black;">
       <%= f.button :submit, "Register" %><% end %>
```

I have a user modal which has validations for the presence of an email address and password.

I have a user/registration_controller with the following create function:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)#(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
      # AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval.deliver

      format.html { redirect_to(root_path, notice: 'Registration received.') }
      format.json { render json: root_path, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to(root_path, alert: 'Sorry! There was a problem with your registration. Please contact us to sort it out.') }
       # format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I have devise helpers in both my application helper and devise helper as follows:

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

My initializers file has two simple form files. One is simple_form.rb. The other is simple_form_bootstrap.rb

No errors display inline in the form. When I complete the form without an email address, I get the error that appears in the create function of my registration_controller.

I'd really like the error to appear inline, in the form, when the user clicks submit.

Does anyone know how to address this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the form submitted through AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have similar line in ur initializer's wrapper

`b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }`

as you mentioned in ur question, please remove `required: false`,
and to remove the '*' for required, change it in config/locale/simple_form.en.yml

```
required:
  text: 'required'
  mark: ''
```

Comment: Thank you. I have written custom jquery to handle the errors (so have not tried to edit either of the simple form or simple form bootstrap initialisers with the suggestion above. I really don't understand why standard functions aren't working with these gems but have worked around the problem. Thanks for the tip about the * in the yml file.

Answer (score 2):

**Does anyone know how to address this problem?**

Because you're able to use an object in the `registration` form, it means you have some liberty over how you display the errors. It would be a different story if you were trying to achieve the same with `login` (as login does not use a form)

--

**Form**

We've done this before (you can see [here](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk) - click "Register" at top):

```
#app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
<%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "email" %>
<div class="error"><%= devise_resource.errors[:email].first if devise_resource.errors[:email].present? %></div>
```

Considering the form uses `devise_resource` in the `form_for` object - this should allow you to display the errors inline

Comment: Hi Rich, Thanks for showing me your example. I think something went wrong with my original post. The opening line of the registration form didn't appear in the published text of my question. I'm using the Simple Form gem. It has a f.error_notification function to it. I'm wondering if that is interfering wit the error notices. I tried adding code similar to yours to my form but it didn't work. I wonder if there is something in Simple Form that is contributing to the issue. Thank you for sharing your approach - if I can't figure this out maybe I can uninstall Simple Form and try it your way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with error validation is resolved if:

1. remove: f.error_nofication from the simple_form call; and
2. insert: <%= devise_error_messages! %> inside the form-inputs field.

If you have validations on your user model and also use devise validatable, the error list at the top of the form will duplicate the errors. Remove one or the other of the validations and you will have the errors working.

I cannot figure out why simple form does not render the errors - but this is a solution.

I have decided to remove simple form from my application - I can't read the documentation and so many questions posted on Stack Overflow relating to using it with devise do not get answered. I cannot see its benefits.

As for the modal - I am going to try using this. http://bootstrapvalidator.com (fingers crossed).  I hope this answer helps someone. I have been trying to set up devise for 3 months - with 3 weeks solid daily effort in trying to understand the docs.

Comment: the method you suggest is currently deprecated in Devise, you should use: `<%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>`

Answer (score 1):

You say you are using modals? But you do not post ajax (no `remote: true` on your form). So I will describe what I think happens now. You do not post ajax, so you post html, so it chooses the `format.html` path, and on error your controller redirects to root-path, with an error message. Instead it should re-render the form.

So uncommenting the commented line in your create action should work :) (and deleting the current `format.html` line obviously).

Ofcourse the re-render will not be a modal. When using modals, and you want the form to remain open, you will have to use ajax and replace the form with a re-rendered version in case of error.

Simple-form, when given an object with validation-errors, will automatically show the errors inline.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I've updated the question to include the opening line of the modal (to show remote true). Do i need it again in the form?  I don't know how to go about replacing the form with a re-rendered form. Do you know how to do that?  Even after deleting and reinstalling both devise and simple form - the errors do not show inline in the form. I'd really love to understand how to get them to display. Do you have any idea about why they might not render, inline, as shown in almost every blog and document associated with simple form and devise? Thank you

Comment: Let me get this straight: when you click the `Register`-link, you show the modal and it contains two links to either sign up with facebook or linkedin? Afaik the `data-toggle` will prevent the default action of following the link, so you will only see the two links. Is that correct?

Comment: It seems you are tackling a lot at the same time: devise and simple-form are new, ajax forms are new, probably even rails is new to you, and then you want to do omniauth. I would focus on getting a simple sign-up flow ready, and gradually make it harder, so you can progress through it. Baby-steps.